# How to compile incremental build based on changes in different modules for specific module(s) only?

Tags: java, maven, build

I have a huge tree of modules that depend on one another in different ways.
There are a number of code modules where I make changes and a few packaging modules that pack different implementation modules in jars/ears/wars etc.

When I only change code in one module I can use `mvn install -amd -pl <changed module(s)>` to only build modules that depend on the modified module.
But I'm only interested in one of the resulting modules though and don't need all the other packaging modules that will be built too.
I could use `mvn install -am -pl <desired module(s)>`, but that would also build modules that didn't change and the build would take even longer than with my other solution.

What I need is a way to combine `-amd` and `-am` with *different* project lists for each parameter. Something like `mvn install -amd <changed module(s)> -am <desired module(s)>`. It would only build modules that depend on my changed module but are also in the dependency tree for the desired packaging module.

Comment: Are you sure you've got that right? My reading of `-am` is that it builds *dependencies* of the listed projects.  So once everything is built `-amd -pl <changed modules>` is the only thing you'd ever want to run.

Comment: If you already use *mvn -amd -pl ...* than only the modules will be built which have been changed and on which other dependent on. So you wrote: *but that would also build modules that didn't change*. That sounds like your dependencies between your modules isn't correct?.

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot: Sorry, I mixed up -am and -amd

Comment: @khmarbaise: You right, but I fixed my question now and I hope it makes more sense:
`mvn -amd -pl` builds everything in the project list and modules that depend on them. But I don't want to build ALL modules that depend on them. Only modules that depend on them that are required for the build of a specific packaging module.

Let's say I have a module for building an EAR and a module for building a WAR and I only need a new WAR, but I can't build the WAR with -am because that would basically build the entire project. And using -amd on my changes would build the EAR too.

Comment: May be you can try to manually give the modules simply by *mvn -pl mod1 mod-war* etc. ? Wouldn't that solve the problem. So you control exactly what is being built. But you have to be sure and may be you forget something.

Comment: @khmarbaise: Sadly the dependency tree is so complex that I would probably spend more time looking for the correct modules and fixing the order than a full build would take.